# seeking a script or similar in Ubuntu 22.04 to monitor a program's text window for changes and audibly notify me

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, window

I am an amateur radio operator and I use a program called PyQSO to both log my successful contacts and also to monitor changes in what is called a "DX cluster."  There are many such clusters online and it allows amateur operators from around the world to post who they just last conversed with in case others want to try.

Anyway, I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  I have the PyQSO program set up in such a way to filter out not wanted countries and only allow those that I need to contact.  When a needed country appears and a person had a successful contact, if they post it on the "cluster", the PyQSO program has a text  window showing the entry with all of the information I need.  I then immediately know where to go and who I am going to try and contact.  These text notification lines are essentially visual alerts.

Here's the problem, however, that I hope someone can solve: I would like to also get an audio alert.  It can be quite inconvenient to have to watch the text window often for any potential new contacts and it would be great to just minimize the window and carry on with other work on the PC.  Then, an audio beep occurs when a new contact is received, and I can maximize the window to see who it is.  Unfortunately, the PyQSO program does not have such an option.

Is there a script or similar Ubuntu set up that I could use to monitor the text window for new changes and then get audio notified when they occur, whether the PyQSO text window is maximized or minimized?

PLEASE, you'll really have to "spell out" such a script.  In other words, please don't be vague as I seldom work with scripts and commands.  For reference, the PyQSO program was installed and resides wherever the Ubuntu software installer placed it.  The text window is open on my desktop screen.

Thanks in advance for any assistance and I bid you a fine day.

Comment: Instead of checking this externally, the best approach might be to modify the source code. Checking `pyqso` on Github, it seems rather well commented.

Comment: Are you able to start pyqso in a x11-console-window? If so you can configure the window to alert on changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no general easy way to do this.

If you're exceptionally nice, you could go to the [issue report page](https://github.com/ctjacobs/pyqso/issues) and report what you'd need. Remember the author does this in his spare time - any second spent on working on pyqso is one that he can not be spending with friends or family, sleeping or working for money, so be honest about that it's *your* need, but explain clearly what workflow you want to enable. He's an expert on the domain you're working in - I'm having a hard time even understanding why you'd want to instantly know something happens somewhere else, so he might have good ideas on how to implement that in his software. Might be that waiting for the window to open to trigger the sound is a backwards way of approaching all this, and something much easier is possible!

Sadly, we're not experts on this particular piece of software, so we can't tell. I can just talk from general software development experience when I say that probably, the idea that you watch some other program's windows to get notified is a bit of a unnecessary complication, and would usually instead be much better solved at the *origin* of the change in state that leads to some part of the program to open a window.

Answer (score 0):

This is very doable, but you need to run it from terminal to see if you can directly capture the output with bash, or if you can grab it directly from one of [these submodules](https://pyqso.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to really get started.

---

Install the `pygame` library.

```
pip install pygame
```

[Here's a great place find a sound you like.](https://pixabay.com/sound-effects/search/notification/) 
You can use the following command to convert any audio/video file to `.wav` format.

```
ffmpeg -i your_mpeg_audio.mp3 your_wav_audio.wav
```

Replace `/path/to/alert.wav` with the actual path to your alert sound file.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gi import require_version
require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
import pygame
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
import logging
import telnetlib
import os.path
import sys

# Import the PyQSO and DXCluster classes
from pyqso import PyQSO
from dx_cluster import DXCluster

class MyDXCluster(DXCluster):
    def __init__(self, application):
        super().__init__(application)
        self.previous_data = set()

        # Initialize pygame mixer
        pygame.mixer.init()

        # Set the alert sound file
        self.alert_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("../alert.wav")

        # Schedule the on_telnet_io method to be called every 20 seconds (20000 milliseconds)
        GObject.timeout_add(20000, self.on_telnet_io)

    def on_telnet_io(self):
        """ Retrieve any new data from the Telnet server and handle it.

        :returns: Always returns True to satisfy the GObject timer.
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if self.connection:
            text = self.connection.read_very_eager()
            text = text.decode("ascii", "replace")

            # Check for new entries
            new_entries = self.detect_new_entries(text)

            # Play alert sound if new entries are detected
            if new_entries:
                self.alert_sound.play()

            # Call the original on_telnet_io method for other functionalities
            super().on_telnet_io()

        return True

    def detect_new_entries(self, text):
        """ Detect new entries in the received text.
        :param str text: The text received from the Telnet server.
        :returns: Always returns True to trigger the alert sound.
        :rtype: bool
        """
        return True

def main():
    # This creates the 'application' object
    application = PyQSO(logbook_path="../*.db")

    # Use your modified DXCluster class
    dx_cluster = MyDXCluster(application)

    # Connect to the DX cluster
    dx_cluster.new_server()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Gtk.main()
```

I was able to get this to work as a standalone directory: [pyqso-mod.zip](http://tinyurl.com/4zfdvs8d)

[The PyQSO Github page](https://github.com/ctjacobs/pyqso) says:

> "...PyQSO can be run without installation by issuing the following
> command in the terminal: `python3 bin/pyqso`

This way, you don't have to interfere with the current installation. The `.zip` contains a directory of the same name. Run with: `python3 ./pyqso-mod/pyqso/my_pyqso_script.sh`

I had to consolidate the main program with the script directory to make it simple. I stripped the paths from all the imports in the `.py` files. There were some Gtk 4.0 warnings, but it was running. The Gtk messages were resolved using `require_version`. The problem comes with `world_map.py`

**Do not install `cartopy`.**

The app will only work without it! *(Toolbox will not show 'world map')* This is a current bug in `PyQSO` itself. [I did comment](https://github.com/ctjacobs/pyqso/issues/78#issuecomment-1899760942) on the current issue that's been submitted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150932/discussion-between-j-cravens-and-eric).